# Download and install Ning on other servers

Tags: social-networking

Is it possible to download and install Ning on one's own server? Also does anyone ning's license.

My sense is that you cannot install Ning locally or on a test server. If that is the case does anyone know a good open source social networking platform?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Ning is a hosted application, you can't download it. I would try [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org): www.elgg.org - it's open source and pretty mature at this point.

There are also various modules/plugins for various CMSs (Drupal, Plone, Joomla, WordPress, etc.) that you can use to add socnet functionality to a site.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity from Telerik has a Social Network starter pack if you into ASP.NET programming.

Answer (score 0):

that's not hard. if you pay the monthly fee to get rid of their google ads, you can redirect your ning address to any URL you wish (it will still be hosted on their servers though)